# R creates a different sequence of numbers

Tags: r

Newbie here

I want an equidistant series of numbers between 0 and 20.

Why do I get two different sets of numbers?

```
0:20
#[1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

seq(0:20)
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: The answer is in the documentation for `?seq` but you have to read it carefully and slowly. Specifically, note that your second attempt is equivalent to `seq(from = 0:20)`.

Comment: Use `seq(0,20)` for parity

Answer (score 4):

Apparently when you pass a vector to seq(), it just prints 1:length(vector), as in

```
> seq(c(2, 4, 6, 100))
[1] 1 2 3 4
> seq(c('a', 2, mean))
[1] 1 2 3
```

I don't think that's how you typically use seq(). You'll get the behavior you expect if you pass the first value in the sequence, the last value, and optionally the length of the output or the step size. Better would be

```
> seq(0, 20)
 [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
> seq(from = 0, to = 20)
 [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the **seq** header from the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.2/topics/seq).

```
seq(from = 1, to = 1, by = ((to - from)/(length.out - 1)), ...)
```

To achieve the same behaviour as the first statement you should call it with 2 parameters (**from** and **to**).

In your second statement you are calling it with only one parameter and it seems that it is using the length of the given parameter as the number of elements to generate from the default **from** value, which is 1.

Check this quick example, with a 6-elements vector:

```
> seq(c(1,4,5,6,2,3))
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

In your case, the length of the list 0:20 is 20 and generates 20 numbers from 1: 1,2,...,21